# find out which program delete my files

Tags: windows-server-2008

My files has been deleted randomly sometimes.
I need to find out which proccess delete this files.
Does windows log anything that can help?
Or is there any third party app that can monitor apps that have I/O operation
My os is windows 2008 r2
Please help I can't figure out which program is causing this.

Comment: What you need is [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor). I wouldn't be without it.

Comment: which filter should i set? I dont find delete filter

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could modify this powershell to maybe do what you're looking to do. 

    https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b#content

This script uses the .net FileSystemWatcher class to subscribe to 'create', 'change' and 'delete' events on files or folders in the NTFS filesystem.

You can probably modify this to monitor the folders in question and use process monitor to see what I/O operation is deleting the files? 

Totally just a guess though.

Comment: You should turn on file auditing so that the next time they get deleted you'll have logs of it. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771070.aspx, http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Auditing_Windows_Server_2008_File_and_Folder_Access

Comment: The system way to delete files is through `SetDispositionInformationFile`, but don't look for this: filter instead for `Detail contains Delete:`. Alternatively use `Path contains ` and enter the name or directory of the files that are being deleted.

Comment: Thanks all of you your solution seems correct but AFH 's solution seems simpler.I set the filter and I'm waiting for result. @AFH if it is needed to mark as answer please write a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SysInternals are well-known for producing extremely useful diagnostic tools, and the one to use in this case is [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor). You can down-load it individually, or as part of the [Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062), which is well worth having, especially Process Explorer, which is a much-enhanced replacement for Task Manager. All the utilities are freeware.

You simply down-load the ZIP file and extract to a directory of your choice, then run from there. Each utility requires acceptance of licensing conditions when first run, but no installation is required.

Note that in order to filter file deletions there is no `FileDelete` operation: at a system level deletions are performed by `SetDispositionInformationFile` and if successful show `Delete: True` in the **Detail** column, so searching for `Detail contains Delete:` will find all deletion attempts. Alternatively or additionally you can search for the directory / partial name of the files being deleted in `Path contains`.